# similarity of the expansions of $e^x$ and $(1+x)^n$

Tags: soft-question, taylor-expansion, exponential-function, binomial-theorem

Is there a reason behind why the expansion of $(1+x)^n$ looks very similar to the taylor series expansion of $e^x$?

Comment: How are they similar?

Answer (score 4):

The fact that$$(\forall x\in\mathbb{C}):e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$$leads naturally to similarities.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of it in terms of the **exponential generating funtions** of a given sequence: $a_0,a_1,a_2\ldots$ defined as:
$$a(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}.$$
When $f_{n}=1$, $\forall\, n\geq 0$ you have:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_{n}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}=e^{x}$$
When $\alpha$ is a natural number and $g_n$ is the sequence defined as:
$$g_{n}=\begin{cases}
\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1) & \alpha\leq n\\ 
\qquad 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases},\quad \forall\, n\geq 0$$ 
you have:
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g_{n}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)\frac{x^{n}}{n!}=(1+x)^{\alpha}$$

Comment: shouldn't it be $\alpha(\alpha-1)...(\alpha-n-1)$

Comment: No, because is the falling factorial $p_{n}(x):=x(x-1)\cdot(x-(n-1))=x(x-1)\cdots(x-n+1)$.

Comment: oh okay. thanks

Comment: Your welcome :)